# How to avoid two or more returns in Java method

Tags: java, string, methods, return

I have this method which validates a string.

In my assignment I can't have more than 1 return in a method.

How can I make this method in a way to return only one value at the end after the do while loop ?

```
public final static String CHOIX_MENUS_VALIDES = "1234";    

public static String validateMenu() {
            
     String choice;
     String choice1 = String.valueOf(CHOIX_MENUS_VALIDES.charAt(0));
     String choice2 = String.valueOf(CHOIX_MENUS_VALIDES.charAt(1));
     String choice3 = String.valueOf(CHOIX_MENUS_VALIDES.charAt(2));
     String choice4 = String.valueOf(CHOIX_MENUS_VALIDES.charAt(3));
    
     do {
         choice = validateString(MSG_SOLL_MENU, MSG_ERR_MENU, 1, 4, true);
    
         if (choice.trim().equals(choice1) || choice.trim().equals(choice2) || choice.trim().equals(choice3) || choice.trim().equals(choice4)) {
            return choice; //Here I don't want to return the choice 
         }
         if (!choice.equals(choice1) || !choice.equals(choice2) || !choice.equals(choice3) || !choice.equals(choice4)) {
            System.out.println(MSG_ERR_MENU);
         }
    
    } while(!choice.trim().equals(choice1) || !choice.trim().equals(choice2) || !choice.trim().equals(choice3) || !choice.trim().equals(choice4));
    
   return choice;
}
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me rebuild that method for returning only one value at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simples solution is to replace the first return

`return choice;` //Here I don't want to return the choice

by a `break`;

Another solution is to use a boolean variable (lets named `stay`)

```
 do{
      boolean stay = true;
      choice = validateString(MSG_SOLL_MENU, MSG_ERR_MENU, 1, 4, true);

      if (...){
          stay = false; 
      }
      else if(...)   {...}
  while(stay && ...);

  return choice;
```

In every loop iteration you set the variable to `true` (*i.e.,*  `boolean stay = true;`) so that you only get out of the loop due to that variable being set to `false`. Because we removed the first `return` from the first `if(..)` and added now the variable we had to change the second `if` to an `else if` so that it does not get executed if the first `if` evaluates to true. Finally, you add the new variable as part of your while condition.